# rails select multiple array option,non model field validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, model

How to validate this field in model:

```
<tr>
  <th><%= f.label :Contacts, :class => 'control-label' %></th>
  <td>
    <%= select_tag "contacts[]", options_for_select(@contact.collect{|x| [x.firstname+" "+x.lastname ,x.id]}, @selected_array ), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I tried this:

```
attr_accessor  :contacts  
validates :contacts, :presence => true
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Are your other validations working properly..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use validations you need a model. What you maybe need is a model that is not backed in the DB. You can just:

```
include ActiveModel::Validations
```

in the model Class definition. Check this railscast:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model